# The connection string property has not been initialized using Dapper to get the data from SQL Server 2014 database

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, dapper, c#-8.0

I am using Dapper along with asp.net web api 2 to fetch data from SQL Server 2014 database.

Here goes my code details :

TestController.cs

```
    // GET api/<controller>
    [Route("allcountrygroups")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCountryGroups()
    {
        var countrygroups = await _countryService.GetCountryGroupsAsync(locale);
        return (countrygroups == null ? (IHttpActionResult)NotFound() : Ok(countrygroups));
    }
```

ITestService.cs

```
public interface ICountryService
{
    Task<List<CountryGroupContentNewDTO>> GetCountryGroupsAsync(string locale);
}
```

TestService.cs

```
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    private readonly ICommonService _commonService;
    private IDbConnection _dbConnection = null;
    public TestService(ICommonService commonService)
    {
        _commonService = commonService;
        _dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultConnection"]);
    }

    public async Task<List<CountryGroupContentNewDTO>> GetCountryGroupsAsync(string locale)
    {
        NLogLogger.Info("Entered CountryGroups API with locale " + locale);
        var localeLangId = _commonService.GetLanguageFromLocale(locale).LanguageId;
        var dftLanguageId = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultLanguageId"]);
        var query = "select * from TestTable";
        var result = new Dictionary<int, CountryGroupContentNewDTO>();
        await _dbConnection.QueryAsync<CountryGroupContentNewDTO, CountryVM, CountryGroupContentNewDTO>(query, (cg, c) =>
        {
            CountryGroupContentNewDTO cgroup;
            if (!result.TryGetValue(cg.CountryGroupId, out cgroup))
            {
                result.Add(cg.CountryGroupId, cgroup = cg);
            }

            cgroup.CountryGroupAssociatedCountries.Add(c);
            return cgroup;
        }

        , splitOn: "CountryGroupId");
        NLogLogger.Info("Returning from CountryGroups API with result");
        return result.Values.ToList();
    }
}
```

On executing the code I am getting an error : The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code below and all started working fine as expected:

TestService.cs

```
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    private readonly ICommonService _commonService;
    private IDbConnection _dbConnection = null;
    public TestService(ICommonService commonService)
    {
        _commonService = commonService;
        _dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
    }

    public async Task<List<CountryGroupContentNewDTO>> GetCountryGroupsAsync(string locale)
    {
        NLogLogger.Info("Entered CountryGroups API with locale " + locale);
        var localeLangId = _commonService.GetLanguageFromLocale(locale).LanguageId;
        var dftLanguageId = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultLanguageId"]);
        var query = "select * from TestTable";
        var result = new Dictionary<int, CountryGroupContentNewDTO>();
        await _dbConnection.QueryAsync<CountryGroupContentNewDTO, CountryVM, CountryGroupContentNewDTO>(query, (cg, c) =>
        {
            CountryGroupContentNewDTO cgroup;
            if (!result.TryGetValue(cg.CountryGroupId, out cgroup))
            {
                result.Add(cg.CountryGroupId, cgroup = cg);
            }

            cgroup.CountryGroupAssociatedCountries.Add(c);
            return cgroup;
        }

        , splitOn: "CountryId");
        NLogLogger.Info("Returning from CountryGroups API with result");
        return result.Values.ToList();
    }
}
```